# XCode 5 Storyboard Tab Bar Icons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uistoryboard

So I'm attempting to create custom icons for an iOS Application using the Tabbed View Layout setup and following the guidelines on the Apple Developers website which says:

> iPhone 5/Touch (High Res):  About 50 x 50 (maximum: 96 x 64)
>   iPhone/Touch (High Res):  About 50 x 50 (maximum: 96 x 64)
>   iPad/iPad Mini (High Res):  About 50 x 50 (maximum: 96 x 64)
>  iPad
>   2/iPad Mini (Standard Res):  About 25 x 25 (maximum: 48 x 32)
>
> Non-Interlaced 24 bit PNGs with Alpha recommended.

And according to the site they are pixel measurements.

My trouble is that I created an image icon which measures 50x50 pixels and when using the interface options and changing the tab image to that of the created 50x50 image it's too big and cuts off the bottom half of the icon. My work space is of an iPhone 5 Retina 64bit but it seems that a 25 x 25 image would be fit yet that's a standard resolution image and would look awful on retina devices.

Any wonder to why my 50 x 50 icon is too big for layout?

Below is a screenshot if any code is needed let me know where from. This is my first attempt at using the Storyboard Layout and haven't had to add much code myself as the interface has done it all mostly.

[image: Screenshot of Storyboard with oversized icon and the pane I set the icon from] 
As per instructed I renamed the image to include @2x at the end. This has slightly worked and the first icon is displaying a little more of the 50x50 image but not all of it.

Image below shows the tab displaying more of the image.
[image]

Comment: Did you named it with @2x, and put its "source" without the @2x?

Comment: @Larme Hmm I didn't use 2x as I didn't think it would be necessary as I only have one file and the one file I created was of the smaller size mentioned on Apple's table above. I shall do this now though.

Update: Adding 2x on the end of the files as mentioned above did make the image slightly smaller but there is still a fair bit of it cut off.

Comment: Thank you @Larme I realised there was 2 issues at hand one was this 2x rule another was when I exported from Adobe Illustrator the size was 50x50 yet the final resolution came out 208x201. I have since fixed it and all is good!